# ngAnimate on transcluded directive

Tags: angularjs, ng-animate

I would like to have a a directive that notifies the user that data has changed, (for example by changing the bg color, shaking, sliding etc).  A **simple** example would be something like this:

html:

```
<change watch="heartbeat">{{heartbeat}}</change>
```

directive:

```
angular.module('module').directive('change', function($timeout) {

    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            scope.$watch(attrs.watch, function(value) {
                element.addClass("changed");
                $timeout(function() {
                    element.removeClass("changed");
                }, 600);
            });
        }
    }
});
```

How can I change the above directive so that it uses the ngAnimate functionality?  I've been looking at the $animator service, but I can't work out how to fit it into the above model.

Comment: What does this question have to do with transclusion? It doesn't seem that you're using transclusion with this example directive.

Comment: @Jmr I stripped out the explicit transclusion to keep the example simple as the simple background change did not require a templete.  In the above code adding template: <span ng-transclude></span> wouldn't change the link function.

Comment: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LMC8V/) with an explicit transclusion.  It's the same problem, explicit or implicit transclusion.  How do you use the ngAnimate functionality in a directive that wraps other content?

Comment: In 1.1.5 you can use a custom animation for this instead of using addClass/removeClass http://www.yearofmoo.com/2013/05/enhanced-animations-in-angularjs.html#custom-animations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is currently not possible.

The `ngAnimate` directive only supports 5 predefined types of animation-triggering events at this moment (v1.1.4):

- enter
- leave
- move
- show
- hide

Each of the above is coupled with specific DOM manipulating operation, and what you are looking to achieve doesn't fit into any of these 5 categories, so perhaps not until custom animation events are being supported.

More explanations can be found here:
http://gsklee.im/post/50254705713/nganimate-your-angularjs-apps-with-css3-and-jquery

Comment: Please mention custom animations as well. These are supported in 1.1.5. http://www.yearofmoo.com/2013/05/enhanced-animations-in-angularjs.html#custom-animations